# How to pass rendered Vue component as parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome, v-tooltip

I use Vue, vue-fontawesome and v-tooltip. What I simply try to do is this:

```
<button v-tooltip="<fa icon='sign-out-alt'/>">Upgrade</button>
```

But that doesn't work, component passed as strings are not rendered. How to get it done easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific use case, there's an [example for that](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#component) in v-tooltip readme

> If you need to display components inside the tooltip (or
>   popover/dropdown, technically it's the same ), use the v-popover
>   component

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/w4dh05yt/) of using a child component as a popover. Instead of my child component, you would use your `<fa icon='sign-out-alt'/>` icon.